# I don't understand array statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am following the 2D breakout game tutorial on the Mozilla website. There is a bit of code that I do not understand.

```
var brickRowCount = 3;
var brickColumnCount = 5;
var brickWidth = 75;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;

var bricks = [];
for(c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    bricks[c] = []; // <-- here
    for(r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
        bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // <-- here
    }
}
```

I understand in general what the code does, however, there are a few lines that are unclear exactly what they do. According to the website, "We will hold all our bricks in a two-dimensional array. It will contain the brick columns (c), which in turn will contain the brick rows (r), which in turn will each contain an object containing the x and y position to paint each brick on the screen."

I have put comments next to the lines of code that I specifically do not understand. Can someone please clarify exactly what these statements mean?

Thank you

Comment: they're just initializing an array of arrays of objects. that's all. `[]` is a new blank/empty array.

Answer (score 3):

it is creating a multidimensional array, or another way to call it, an array of array.

Each element of the array is another array, so to access them you need to use multiple `[]` for each dimension.. And just like any other array, they need to be initialized.

So here

```
bricks[c] = [];
```

it is initializing for each element of array `bricks` an array

```
bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0 };
```

here is storing an object in the position `r` in the array `bricks[c]` (which means the element in the position `c` in array `bricks` is an array too)

Answer (score 2):

Some comments that might help

```
// create a new empty array, `[]`, in `bricks` at position `c`
bricks[c] = []

// create a new brick, {x:0,y:0}, in `bricks[c]` at position `r`
bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0 };
```

Answer (score 1):

`bricks[c]` is an array within the bricks array.

`bricks[c][r]` contains the coordinates of the brick.

It's creating the array bricks, then within it, it is creating an array of `c` and adding values using `r`.

Could write it like this for you to visualize: `bricks[bricks[c][r]]`

Answer (score 0):

It says that at position `(c,r)` in the array a [literal object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) is placed containing two fields: `x` and `y`. Both these fields have the value `0`

The syntax `{x: 0 ,y: 0}` is a shorthand for creating an object containing two fields and assigning a value to these fields at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

`bricks[c] = []` sets array element number `c` to be an empty array.

E.g. if you run the for loop without the second part:

```
var bricks = [];
for(c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
   bricks[c] = [];
}
```

`bricks` will be `[ [ ], [ ], [ ], [ ], [ ] ]`

If you run the full code, `bricks` will be

```
[
  [ { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 } ],
  [ { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 } ],
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of that as a matrix, where `c` is columns, `r` is rows, and `x` is the cell at intersection `cr`

```
c\r r0   r1   r2   ..  rn
c0  x00  x01  x02  ..  x0n
c1  x10  x11  x12  ..  x1n  
..  ..   ..   ..   ..  ..
cn  xn0  xn1  xn2  ..  xnn
```

The array has to be initialized (that is what presented in your code), that every cell of the array (matrix) will be assigned with a value and probably (just my guess) the value will be changed trough the events happening during the game, or they will be checked or both.